# jQuery AJAX POST on Rails migraine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm running a JS game off file:// and trying to make a post request to a localhost Rails server to add a high score entry.

JS:

```
  highScoresEntryView.keyHandlers = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.parent.keydown(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      if(event.which == 27) {
        //...
      } else if (event.which == 13) {
        if(that.entryString !== "") {
          that.scoreObject.score.player = that.entryString;
          that.submitScore(that.scoreObject);
        } else { 
          AsteroidsUI.initializeMainMenu();
        }
      }
    });
  };

  highScoresEntryView.submitScore = function() {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: AsteroidsUI.highScoresHost, //http://localhost:3000/scores/
      data: that.scoreObject,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        alert("Congrobulations! Score sent.");
        AsteroidsUI.initializeMainMenu();
      },
      error: function(a, b, c) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        alert("Could not send score :(");
        AsteroidsUI.initializeHighScoresEntry(that.scoreObject);
      }
    });
  };
```

Controller:

```
  def create
    @score = Score.new(params[:score])
    if @score.save
      render :json => @score, :status => 201
    else
      render :json => { :errors => @score.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422
    end
  end
```

I get a response back with status 201 and the database makes an entry, but when I check the response in firebug, it appears blank and the error handler for the ajax request fires rather than the success handler. I've looked through about a dozen similar questions and none of the solutions have worked for me so far - I've tried changing dataType between text, html, and json, same outcome.

Comment: When are you sending the request? Could post the whole js code in which this `$.ajax` is called?

Comment: Can you remove the status part and try it?

Comment: @H-man When status is removed, I get the same outcome, just with a 200 OK code. The response is blank. The response object, as interpreted by console.log, is this:
 
readyState 0
responseText ""
status 0
statusText "error"

Comment: @Andrei I'm sending this request following an enter keypress on which stopPropagate and preventDefault is called. I'm updating my question with the full context now.

Comment: Few things to check, `as_json` on `score.rb`, calling `submitScore` outside of keypress handler, comment out everything in `create` action  and respond with blank JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a CORS problem. I solved it by adding the following code similar to [this tutorial](http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/) to my Rails controller:

```
  def set_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'ETag'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
  end
```

I'm not really sure why this worked to allow the success callback. Does AJAX require these headers in the response to engage the success callback?